# Dynamically hide module from package in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, module, r-mapedit

I try to build an application that dynamically shows and hides modules. Following this [tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/shiny-add-removing-modules-dynamically/)  and this [code](https://github.com/jonas-hag/dynamic_shiny_modules/blob/main/01_templates/template_3.R), I can show and remove modules built by my own. However, when calling a module from an external package (e.g from [mapedit](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit) the *editModu* module) this UI can not be removed through the provided workflow.
What is the proper way to remove UI from modules that have been loaded with a package?

So far I used the following code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(mapedit)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(
    inputId = "add_module",
    label = "Add a module"
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "remove_module",
    label = "Remove a module"
  ),
  div(
    id = "add_here"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  active_modules <- reactiveVal(value = NULL)
  
  # leaflet blank map for module
    map<-leaflet()%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
    
  observeEvent(input$add_module, {
    current_id <- paste0("id_", input$add_module)
    active_modules(c(current_id, active_modules()))
    
    callModule(editMod, map,id = current_id)
    
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add_here",
      ui = editModUI(id = current_id)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_module, {
    
    # only remove a module if there is at least one module shown
    if (length(active_modules()) > 0) {
      current_id <- active_modules()[1]
      removeUI(
        selector = paste0("#", current_id)
      )
      
      # update the list of currently shown modules
      active_modules(active_modules()[-1])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provided, the module loaded with "add_module" is not called *#id_n*, but *#id_n-map*; you need to change the selector name in `removeUI` for:

```
  removeUI(
    selector = paste0("#", current_id, "-map")
  )
```

You can check the id of any element from your shiny app by right clicking in the browser, selecting "Inspect Element" and looking for the element of interest.